# PHPStorm - not finding inner objects' methods

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, phpstorm

I'm working on PHPStorm and changing a PHP project from procedural code to OOP, however, when changing to OOP PHP doesn't seem to find objects' methods, here's a picture

[image: problem]

how do I solve this? Or should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is because you should use

```
/**
 * @var RegistrationDB 
 */
var $db;
/**
 * @var Notifier 
 */
var $notifier;

function __construct() {
    $this->db = new RegistrationDB();
    $this->notifier = new Notifier();
}
```

in the constructor,

```
if (!$this->db->hasUser($email)) ...
```

when you try to reference the property (underpinned by the var $db).

EDIT : added phpdoc pragmas to render the property's class resolvable.

EDIT 2 : in php OOP, the object's properties are declared by a var. So, `var $db;` implies that a `db` property exists for the classes' instance objects

```
var $db; in class Foo

...

$a = new Foo();
$a->db;  // correct
$a->$db; // very probable runtime error
```

for example, from one of my current projects :

```
$clinic = \DAO\clinics::insert( true , 'Funky Clinic inc' , new DateTime('now'));
$clinic->active = true;
$logger->info($clinic);
$clinic->$active = false;  // <- this is line 20 from the stack trace
```

The third line will log properly the object to my log file, while line 4 will bomb with the following error in the console :

```
> php TestPatient.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in /Users/yvesleborg/devel/Shiva/MyClient/HisProject/DAO/SQL/v1.0/TestPatient.php on line 20
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}()     /Users/yvesleborg/devel/Shiva/MyClient/HisProject/DAO/SQL/v1.0/TestPatient.php:0
```

Comment: nevermind, restarting phpstorm seemed to do the trick. thanks anyway man, +1

EDIT: can you explain whats the difference between "$this->$something" and "$this->something"?

Comment: well, whatever fixed the issue then. Still beware of $this->$something, you may get some pretty funky runtime errors at runtime. Prefer $this->something when referencing properties declared with a var. I also edited my answer to make the class very explicit.

Comment: @DarkW ... added concrete example of proper referencing for object's properties.